# Maximum and minum value for the entropy summation formula

Tags: probability, entropy, data-mining

Suppose $t$ is a non empty set divided in $j$ different classes and consider $p_j$ the relative frequency of the elements of class $j$ with respect to all the elements of the set $t$. Consider the entroyp formula $\sum_j p_j\times \log p_j$.

I would like to prove that

$-\log j\leq $ $\sum_j p_j\times \log p_j$ $\leq 0 $

$\sum_j p_j\times \log p_j$ $\leq 0$

should follow from the fact that for every product $ p_j\times \log p_j $ in the summation, it is at most 0 (when $p_j=1$ or $p_j=0$, and less then 0 if it has a value in the interval (0,1) ). I do not know how to show that

1. $-\log j\leq $ $\sum_j p_j\times \log p_j$

and

2. $-\log j = $ $\sum_j p_j\times \log p_j$ if and only if $p_j=1/j$ (implying that the minimum value of the summation is reached when every relative frequency is exactly the same.